# Can we set fact type and fact field dynamically in Drools

Tags: java, json, drools, pojo

How do I set fact type and fact field dynamically in drl file?I am reading a json file which having the records.that records I am mapping to pojo class which is generating dynamically from json schema I used [json2pojo maven plugin](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)! .now I want to fire some rules on that class. but I am not able to fech that class in drl file as a fact.same for fields.
below is drl rule.

```
rule "not null"

when 

  obj:Class(fieldName==null)
then
  //take action
end
```

this Class and fieldName is generating dynamically.
please suggest me solution regarding this.
Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. You have a JSON file holding the name of a class and its attributes, and you want to refer to those names and attributes in the Drools file? I don't think Drools supports placeholders for class names. Have you thought about generating the Drools file after reading the JSON?

Comment: yes, but in my case I have set of rules for validation like not null,required,etc.so my rules are fixed only the input is different.In JSON I have set of records having data of employees. and I have another json schema from that I am genrating class and manping one one record to that class.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully implemented a similar kind of problem statement.  Have a quick look at it.
I was supposed to dynamically generate rules on a sql table selected by the user on runtime in a web application. Point to be noted here is that the pojo class too should be generated at runtime.
Drools 6 has an inbuilt API (similar to JAVA reflection API) where you can dynamically generate a class and hence the factTypes too. 
So first the .drl file :-

```
declare {insert tablename as chosen by the user}
{columnname} : {columntype}  
{columnname} : {columntype}  
end
```

This generates a pojo class alongwith the getters and setters of the attributes which can be directly accessed in the rules.
Now, the java file :-

The generated class can be accessed in  java application  like this:

//get the declared FactType

```
FactType  tableType = kbase.getFactType({packagename},{tablename});
```

//create instances:

```
Object obj = tableType.newInstance();
```

Now, facts were inserted from sql  corresponding to the selected table was implemented via hibernate.  This also kept the table updated if any modifications were made by the rules.

Feel free to ask any questions. 
Happy to help..:)

Comment: Thank you Parul for sharing your implementation idea. Do you have a documentation link or github link for the same?  I am trying to implement the same dynamically for me, but I am not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution according to my requirement.It is an different approach I removed generated POJO dynamically.I created one POJO as "Parameter" which will be used as Fact type.In that I have fields as fieldName(Json field path),rulesToFire(rules),and list of json records.so in drl file I can fetch those values.using com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath I can read respected values.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is good for sending data over the line, etc. But then you should convert it to a POJO and write your validation rules in terms of Java object. I see no good reason why you shouldn't be able to do so.

However... If you want to spend a lot of time and effort...

What you might do has been done using XML, which is another (textual) representation for data sets ("records"). Looking at the JSON structure definition, you can see that you have "objects" and "arrays". These will be your fact types. A (JS-)Object can be represented by a POJO containing a Map, a (JS-)Array might be implemented by a POJO with a java.util.List field.

You can write rules that select a JS-Object and perform field checks.

Comment: Thanks @laune for reply. Actually I tried with pojo class but I was not able to fetch it dynamically in drl file. and again I have to fetch data from that object so because of nested object it will be complex. so I tried with different way which I commented.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in `FactType` interface as `setFromMap`. If you are able to provide your input in a `Map` collection (may be JSON, or JSON to `Map`) then you can set all of the properties of your declared type from this `Map`. Below is a test case for this approach. I hope it is gonna be helpful.

```
   @Test
    void test_StatelessKieSession_DynamicRuleNestedObjects_DeclaredVariables_Standalone() throws Exception{
        Map<String,Object> fields =
                Stream.of(new Object[][] {
                        {"name","server001"},
                        {"processors",4},
                        {"memory",8192},
                        {"diskSpace",128},
                        {"cpuUsage",3},
                        {"virtualizations"
                                ,Stream.of(
                                new HashMap<String,Object>(){{
                                    put("name","virtualization - 1");
                                    put("diskSpace",4);
                                    put("memory",1024);}},
                                new HashMap<String,Object>(){{
                                    put("name","virtualization - 2");
                                    put("diskSpace",8);
                                    put("memory",2048);}}
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList())}
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> (String)key[0], val -> val[1]));

        String packageName = "com.genericrule";
        String mainObjectName = "Server";

        String ruleStr = "package com.genericrule import java.util.List; declare Server name : String processors : int memory : int diskSpace : int virtualizations : List cpuUsage : int ruleMessage : String end; declare Virtualization name : String diskSpace : int memory : int end; rule \"check minimum server configuration\" dialect \"mvel\" when $server : Server(processors < 2 || memory <= 1024 || diskSpace <= 250 ) then $server.ruleMessage = $server.name + \" was rejected by don't apply the minimum configuration.\"; end;";

        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        KieRepository kr = kieServices.getRepository();
        KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

        kfs.write("src/main/resources/genericRule.drl", ruleStr);

        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        kb.buildAll();

        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());

        StatelessKieSession sks = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();

        FactType mainObjectFact = sks.getKieBase().getFactType(packageName,mainObjectName);

        Object mainObject = mainObjectFact.newInstance();

        mainObjectFact.setFromMap(mainObject,fields);
        sks.execute(mainObject);

        assertThat((String) mainObjectFact.get(mainObject,"ruleMessage")).contains("rejected");
    }
```